# ComboBox deixando form lento ao carregar dados winforms C# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Boa noite, estou com um dúvida. Tenho um cadastro de clientes que lista as cidades em um combobox, só que toda vez que abro o cadastro ele carrega os dados e isso deixa lento o carregamento do form, tem alguma forma de fazer a consulta apenas a primeira vez que abre o form e depois reutilizar?

Esse é o Código que popula o checkBox

```
       String nomeConexao = LoginInfo.StringConexao;
       String string_conn = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nomeConexao].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string_conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqle)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
        }
        String CodCidadeEmpresa = DadosEmpresa.CodCidade;

        String sql = "SELECT COD, CIDADE FROM CODMUNICIPIO ORDER BY CIDADE";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
        dtResultado.Clear();
        CbCidade.DataSource = null;
        da.Fill(dtResultado);
        CbCidade.DataSource = dtResultado;
        CbCidade.ValueMember = "COD";
        CbCidade.DisplayMember = "CIDADE";
        CbCidade.SelectedItem = "";
        CbCidade.SelectedValue = CodCidadeEmpresa;
        CbCidade.Refresh();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: blz, Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra opção seria carregar o *DropDown* de forma assíncrona, assim não iria travar o *form* enquanto ele é carregado:

Crie um método assíncrono da seguinte forma:

```
private async void CarregaDropDownCidades()
{
    String nomeConexao = LoginInfo.StringConexao;
    tring string_conn = 
    onfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nomeConexao].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string_conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqle)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
    }
    String CodCidadeEmpresa = DadosEmpresa.CodCidade;

    String sql = "SELECT COD, CIDADE FROM CODMUNICIPIO ORDER BY CIDADE";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
    dtResultado.Clear();    
    da.Fill(dtResultado);

    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        CbCidade.DataSource = null;
        CbCidade.DataSource = dtResultado;
        CbCidade.ValueMember = "COD";
        CbCidade.DisplayMember = "CIDADE";
        CbCidade.SelectedItem = "";
        CbCidade.SelectedValue = CodCidadeEmpresa;
        CbCidade.Refresh();
    }); 
    conn.Close();
}
```

No *load* do seu forma faça a seguinte chamada:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        CarregaDropDownCidades();
    });
}
```

Comment: Cara funcionou muito bem, ele só da uma leve trancadinha no abrir mas nada que se compare ao que era. Muito obrigado. Abraço

Comment: @Rafa Não tem mais itens carregando dados de banco? você pode fazer isso para todos componentes que estejam "pesando" o `load` dor `form`

Comment: Vou dar uma organizada no meu código, certamente deve ter algo.

Answer (score 0):

Tente remover o `ORDER BY CIDADE` do seu select e faça a ordenação diretamente no combo `CbCidade.Sorted = true;`.

Se a dica acima não resolver, tente então o segundo método

Crie uma classe cidades

```
public class Cidades
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string nome {get; set;}
}
```

Depois no form principal crie uma lista publica

```
public List<Cidades> ComboCidades {get; set;}
```

E ai na inicialização do seu sistema você carrega ela com os dados do select

Então quando abrir seu form que possui o combo de cidades você preenche ele com os itens da lista +/- assim

```
CbCidade.DataSource = ComboCidades;
CbCidade.DisplayMember = "nome";
CbCidade.ValueMember = "id";
```